# quantum guesswork of an ensemble

Tags: quantum-information

I am reading an article about quantum guesswork [ Guesswork of a quantum ensemble by michele Dall'Arno ] and i am wondering why he considers ensembles whose traces sum up to 1 in the introduction. I know that the trace of a density matrix is 1 but why their sum over a set also is. Can some one explain this choice to me ?
Thanks